# How to enable Cors with URL Rewrite Sharepoint 2016?

Tags: ajax, web-config, url-rewriting, cors

I am getting CORS policy error. I am trying to use URL Rewrite plug in. I have IIS 10. I tried the examples(links) below, but it still didn't work. So What can i do more?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/fixing-issue-in-making-cross-domain-ajax-call-to-sharepoint-rest/ba-p/510001

https://www.carlosag.net/articles/enable-cors-access-control-allow-origin.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I had that issue too on IIS 10.

Tricks with URL Rewriter and native web.config settings are not working fully.

CORS added in the meanwhile preflight request *(method "OPTION" within request headers)* which is not supported by default by IIS.

At that period I did a custom WebHttpBehavior to handle all of CORS requests then deployed and configured on each IIS front ends.
Unfortunately my source code is obsolete now.

However, you can find a really well implementation of a custom WebHttpBehavior on the GitHub repo [cshandler/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions](https://github.com/cshandler/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions)

The installation and settings are pretty straightforward as the documentation is well done.

Just as reference, the source code I did in the past: [vherrlein/iis-enablingcors](https://github.com/vherrlein/iis-enablingcors)